# how to show value of another component in this exact code Angular 2 and higher

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Good day, I would like to ask you to review this code and help me figure out where is mistake that variable itemCount doesn´t show any value in about.component.html but in home.component.html all work fine. I only want to show itemCount in about.component.html so I tried to use EventEmittent method. Here is code.

```
Home.component.ts
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  itemCount : number = 0; ---here variable in home component ok
  btnText: string = 'Add an item';
  goalText: string = 'My first life goal';
  goals = [];

  @Output()sharedItemCount = new EventEmitter<number>(); -- own event 
 created

  share(){ ---method the invokes own event
    this.sharedItemCount.emit(this.itemCount);
  }

  constructor(private _data: DataService) { }



  ngOnInit() {
    this._data.goal.subscribe(res =>this.goals = res);
    this.itemCount = this.goals.length;
    this._data.changeGoal(this.goals);
    this.share(); --running method to invoke changes with itemCount variable
  }

  addItem(){
    this.goals.push(this.goalText);
    this.goalText = '';
    this.itemCount = this.goals.length;
    this._data.changeGoal(this.goals);
    this.share();--running method to invoke changes with itemCount variable
  }
  removeItem(i){
   this.goals.splice(i,1);
   this.itemCount = this.goals.length;
   this._data.changeGoal(this.goals);
   this.share();--running method to invoke changes with itemCount variable
  }
```

Here is implementation from About.component.html where I want to see value of itemCount.

```
<p (sharedItemCount) = "onShareItemCount($event)">({‌{itemCount}})</p> --receiving own event that invokes onShareItemCount method and passing them value itemCount and also them showing variable itemCount in brackets
```

And here is implementation from About.component.ts

```
export class AboutComponent implements OnInit {
  goals: any;
  itemCount : number; --variable

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, private 
_data: DataService) {
  this.route.params.subscribe(res => console.log(res.id));
  }

ngOnInit() {
this._data.goal.subscribe(res =>this.goals = res);
}

 onShareItemCount(itemCount: number){--method that set up localvariable the 
same as passed through event
    this.itemCount = itemCount;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@Output` event emitter `sharedItemCount` in your `HomeComponent` is useless, you don't need it **because you're already using a shared service** (`_data: DataService`) in both components.

Change your `About.component.html` file to:

```
<p>({‌{itemCount}})</p>
```

And in `About.component.ts` file, change `ngOnInit` function to:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this._data.goal.subscribe(res => {
    this.goals = res;
    this.itemCount = res.length;
  });
}
```

Your `ngOnInit` function gets updated on each change of the goals object using rxjs Observable, resulting on updating your template. Just don't forget to unsubscribe from it on `ngOnDestroy`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but why my new solution doesn´t work? here is the code:
insice data.service.ts
`sharedItemService = new EventEmitter<number>();`
-------
inside home.component.ts
`ngOnInit() {
    ...
    this.sharedItem.sharedItemService.emit(this.itemCount); ---this added
  }`
inside about.component.ts
`ngOnInit() {
...
this.sharedItem.sharedItemService.subscribe((item : number) =>{
  this.itemCount = item;
  });---added
}`
and inside about.component.html just {{itemCount}} 
but still no any value. WHY? this logic should be correct no?subscribe listen to emit.....

Comment: The code you've wrote looks good. Can you make a StackBlitz demo with your problem? The problem could be  from some other part of your code, e.g. maybe you didn't provide well the shared service as a singleton, resulting that one component have one instance of it and the other component as another instance of it